# Useful system stored procedures in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I recently discovered that I could use the `sp_help` to get a table definition and have been hooked onto it since then. Before my discovery, I had to open up the Object explorer in SQL Management studio, manually search for the table name, right click on the table and select Design. That was a lot of effort!

What other system stored procedures do you all use that you can't simply live without?

Comment: Should be community wiki

Answer (score 24, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> is a good [shortcut](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-query-window-short-cuts.aspx) key for `sp_help`.

`sp_helptext` is another goodie for getting stored procedure text.

Comment: Nice.. Can I use Alt + F1 on a particular table similar to sp_help myTable?

Answer (score 13):

All of these undocumented ones

```
xp_getnetname 

xp_fileexist 

xp_dirtree 

xp_subdirs 

sp_who2

xp_getfiledetails 

xp_fixeddrives 

Sp_tempdbspace 

xp_enumdsn 

xp_enumerrorlogs

sp_MSforeachtable 

sp_MSforeachDB
```

See here: [Undocumented stored procedures](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/SQL_Server_Programming_Hacks_-_100%2B_List#Undocumented_but_handy)

And now since SQl Server 2005 all the Dynamic Management Views like [sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Use_the_sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats_dmv_to_check_if_indexes_are_being_used)

Answer (score 11):

sp_ helpindex [table]  - shows you index info (same info as sp_help)

sp_helpconstraint [table] - shows you primary/foreign key/defaults and other constraints *

sp_depends [obj] - shows dependencies of an object, for example:

sp_depends [table] - shows you what stored procs, views, triggers, UDF affect this table

sp_depends [sproc] - shows what tables etc are affected/used by this stored proc

Answer (score 7):

You can use `sp_spaceused` to determine the size of a table or the entire database. If you pass the table name, it returns the space used for that table, when called with no argument it gives the space of the database.

Comment: What a confusing name, by the way! One could think, it was about how many times the `space` character was used. :)

Answer (score 2):

[`sp_who/sp_who2`](http://dotnetyuppie.com/2008/01/03/simple-sql-performance-monitoring-with-sp_who-and-sp_who2/) - lets you know who is doing what on the server.

Answer (score 2):

- [sp_who](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260384(SQL.80).aspx)
- [sp_who2](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14208)
- [sp_helptext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176112.aspx)
- [list of useful system stored procedures](http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/sp_00.htm)

Answer (score 2):

```
sp_catalogs 
sp_column_privileges
sp_column_privileges_ex
sp_columns
sp_columns_ex
sp_databases
sp_cursor
sp_cursorclose
sp_cursorexecute
sp_cursorfetch
sp_cursoroption
sp_cursoropen
sp_cursorprepare
sp_cursorprepexec
sp_cursorunprepare
sp_execute
sp_datatype_info
sp_fkeys
sp_foreignkeys
sp_indexes
sp_pkeys
sp_primarykeys
sp_prepare
sp_prepexec
sp_prepexecrpc
sp_unprepare
sp_server_info
sp_special_columns
sp_sproc_columns
sp_statistics
sp_table_privileges
sp_table_privileges_ex
sp_tables
sp_tables_ex
```

Check This link also

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176007.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Select * From sysobjects where xtype='U' order by Name

Gives a list of all user-defined tables in a database.

Answer (score 1):

[sp_rename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx)

for renaming database objects (tables, columns, indexes, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

master.dbo.xp_cmdshell

I can't list the number of times I didn't have RDP access to a box but did have a SQL login with sufficient permissions to execute that in order to run shell commands on it.

Answer (score 1):

highlight any proc or other system object name in your query editor and hit shift-f1 to get help for that word.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a rather old topic, but it still has a high rank in search engines.

These are my favorite stored procedures, I hope you find them useful too. Almost all of them can be achieved with a simple command, but these stored procedures perform some checks and validation that is useful.

```
[sys].[sp_revokelogin]
[sys].[sp_password]
[sys].[sp_MSchangeobjectowner]
[sys].[sp_addlogin]
[sys].[sp_addrole]
[sys].[sp_adduser]
[sys].[sp_denylogin]
[sys].[sp_droplogin]
[sys].[sp_droprole]
[sys].[sp_droprolemember]
[sys].[sp_dropuser]
```